# How to use dired to open a folder as root

Tags: dired, tramp

I want to batch editing some files as root in dired, however, when I open dired with `/sudo::/my/path/to/dir`, dired window does not list anything.

[image: my dired does not list anything]

What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: Try a trailing foreslash (`/`).

Comment: How do you open that file name? `C-x C-f`? `C-x C-d`?

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus `C-x C-d`

Comment: @Dan the result remains the same

Comment: Can you reproduce when starting Emacs with the `-Q` command-line option? Because I can't.

Comment: Wouldn't you enter `g` to update `dired`, would you?